# Appending Code After Exports List With Rollup.js

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, export, rollupjs

I am using Rollup.js to put together a JavaScript library. I have an initialization function which calls external code that presumes the library is fully loaded. My main JS file looks like this:

```
export * from 'file1';
export * from 'file2';
...

// init code here
```

However Rollup doesn't respect the order and instead outputs:

```
// init code here

exports.obj1 = obj1;
exports.obj2 = obj2;
...
```

When the init code fires, it produces a `ReferenceError` whenever the external code tries to access any of the library's members as they haven't been exported at the time of the call.

I can artificially delay the call with something like `setTimeout(init, 1);` to make it work but that's not by any means an optimal solution and moving the code block manually everytime I build the project gets rather annoying.

Is there some way to force Rollup.js to place some code **after** the exports block?

Comment: Seems like a Rollup bug?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm not sure about this being an actual bug, but I have opened an [issue on the Rollup repo](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1392)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rollup.js has an `outro` option [documented here](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/JavaScript-API#introoutro).

*Thanks to Olsonpm on the [Rollup GitHub](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1392) page*